# Eclipse JNI shared library "architecture word width mismatch) Wrong ELF class UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to access a native C file through my java program. I've created an shared object which eclipse and the project can now see.  The problem I'm getting now is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/sw/libs/xda_core/.1.24.1-1/lib/lib_xda_core_java.so: /opt/sw/libs/xda_core/.1.24.1-1/lib/libxda_core_java.so: ***wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)***

The so is a binary which was made for 64bit architecture. It sounds like there is a mismatch in the JVM and the so. I checked my JVM and it is a 64 bit runtime. However when I used

***System.Property("sun.arch.data.model") it returned "32"*** I think eclipse is running in a 32 bit JVM and this is why my JNI Native library won't link correctly and I'm getting that error.

Any suggestions? Is this because I have a 32 bit version of eclipse? or is there a way I can force eclipse to use the 64 bit JVM that is installed.

**Edit:** I have tried everyone's suggestions and nothing is working. I've changed the execution, and enviroment variables to point to the newst JDK I have which is 1.6_30.  when I run the program from a command line I get 64 and amd64 as the value when I run the same program in eclise I get 32 and i386.  Something is wrong in eclipse that is causing it to try and run it on a 32 bit JVM.  when I try java -d32 -version it says that a 32 bit enviroment isn't installed but Eclipse doesn't know that.  I've modified the Eclipse.ini file and still nothing is working. I've restarted eclipse after these changes...nothing. Can some one who knows eclipse well people help me out here. thanks

Comment: Can you load the native library outside eclipse? `java -Djava.library.path=...`? Try just a simple main class that loads the library.

Comment: Yes, when I run them by setting the library path they run. It's actually recocnizing the file it's just not able to link it.

Comment: I was getting an unsatesfied link error before this because it could not find the .so file but I fixed that problem and now have this one. It's located the file it's just not able to use it because my JVM is 32 bit for some reason and the file was compiled to binary for 64 bit.

Comment: Do I need to install a new eclipse...a 64 bit version?

Comment: It would be worth a try, but iam wondering about that problem, since the error is thrown by java not eclipse...

Comment: well I don't knwo that much about JNI yet or familiar you are with it but it's loading C code basically and the shared file which is a .so that that error is talking about was compiled and created on a 64 bit machine for a 64bit computer. If the JVM is in 32 bit mode then the words will be the wrong length for computation. I mean that part is pretty obvious 32 bit word vs 64 bit word. I'm just wondering why my eclipse thinks the jvm is 32 when everything I've installed is 64

Comment: AND I've gone throught he eclipse preferences and double checked that they were pointed to 64 bit version JDK's I even checked the oracle website and made sure that what I downloaded was in fact a x86_64 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconfigure Eclipse to use a 64-bit JVM to launch your program, since you've built a 64-bit JNI shared library.

Comment: I've changed the runtime environment and execution enviroment in eclipse to what I believe are 64 bit JDK's available and installed on my computer. However when I run the System.getProperty(sun.arch.data.model) method I get 32. and the JNI class still doesn't work. I'm wondering if I'm setting the JVM correctly?

Comment: So do I, I guess. Did you set it as the default JRE in Preferences/Java/Installed JREs?

Comment: yes, Mines pointed to the jdk1.6.0_30 which is a 64 bit jvm. it's the only one checked.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to change the settings in the Eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I just editted my post. nothing seems to be working although your suggestion "reconfigure eclipse to use 64-bit JVM" is technically correct so far none of the normal ways you'd think of for doing so are having an effect.  So I'll probably mark your answer as correct but my problem ramains.